# PHP Comparing 2 arrays and adding a field when there is a match

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays `dishes`and `favorites`. My goals is to add a field to the `dishes` array if a certain dish occurs in the `favorites`one. This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to be working since I get an empty array back.

```
$boundDishes = [];

foreach ($dishes as $dish) {
    foreach ($favorites as $favorite) {
        if ($favorite == $dish) {
            $dishes['favorite'] = true;
            $boundDishes[] = $dish;
        }
    }
}
return $boundDishes;
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please post the arrays as well.

Comment: `$boundDishes[] = $dishes` must be `$boundDishes[] = $dish;` I suppose

Comment: Do you want add one value in array which must be exists in another array ?

Comment: You are not adding anything to $boundGames - you are adding it to $boundDishes and then returning $boundGames

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I am sorry I copied wrong code I edited OP

Comment: What exactly is `$dishes['favorite'] = true;` supposed to do? It makes no sense and you are modifying the array you're looping through.

Answer (score 0):

To make this an answer, you are returning **$boundGames** but not adding anything to it so that's why it's empty, did you mean to add to **$boundGames** instead of **$boundDishes** in your loop as below?

```
$boundGames = [];

foreach($dishes as $dish) {
    foreach($favorites as $favorite) {
        if($favorite == $dish) {
            $dishes['favorite'] = true;
            $boundGames[] = $dishes;
        }
    }
}
return $boundGames;
```

Alternatively, did you mean to `return $boundDishes`?

Comment: Can you add a var_dump of your **$dishes** and **$favorites** array before they enter the loop so we can see what data you are using exactly?

Comment: I think i found the issue my $dishes array is an array of objects i need to find a way to convert it into a clean array i guess

Comment: Can you type cast using (array) or similar? - if you show us the array of objects we can help further

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$dishes =
[
    'chips',
    'hummus',
    'eggs',
    'ham'
];


$favourites =
[
    'spam',
    'hummus'
];

foreach($favourites as $favourite) {
    if(!in_array($favourite, $dishes)) {
        $dishes[] = $favourite;
    }
}

var_export($dishes);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'chips',
  1 => 'hummus',
  2 => 'eggs',
  3 => 'ham',
  4 => 'spam',
)
```

Or just merge and then filter unique values:

```
$dishes = array_unique(array_merge($dishes, $favourites))
```

Perhaps you just need a helper function:

```
$is_favourite = function($dish) use ($favourites) {
    return in_array($dish, $favourites);
};

echo $is_favourite('spam') ? 'They love spam!' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$boundDishes = [];

foreach ($dishes as $dish) {
    if (in_array($dish, $favourites)) {
        $boundDishes[] = $dish;
    }
}
return $boundDishes;
```